# How to type hint that a variable should be a variable from another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code and the `Book` class has a `type` variable. I've added `str` as the type hint but the type should be either `TYPE_ONE`, `TYPE_TWO` or `TYPE_THREE` from the `Type` class.

How can I do this?

```
class Type:
    TYPE_ONE = 'one'
    TYPE_TWO = 'two'
    TYPE_THREE = 'three'


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Book:
    title: str
    description: str
    type: str  # type should be one attribute of the `Type` class
```

Comment: If only Python had [enumerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an enum instead:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Type(Enum):
    TYPE_ONE = 'one'
    TYPE_TWO = 'two'
    TYPE_THREE = 'three'


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Book:
    title: str
    description: str
    type: Type
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

**Edit:**

Another solution I can think of without using enums is to use `NewType`:

```py
from typing import NewType

TypeAttr = NewType("TypeAttr", str)


class Type:
    TYPE_ONE: TypeAttr = TypeAttr('one')
    TYPE_TWO: TypeAttr = TypeAttr('two')
    TYPE_THREE: TypeAttr = TypeAttr('three')


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Book:
    title: str
    description: str
    type: TypeAttr
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype

Unfortunately, it can easily be broken by doing:

```py
b = Book("title", "description", TypeAttr("not Type attribute"))
```

but I can't think on another solution right now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The code example is very simplified and I can't just switch to Enums. Do you know a solution for my code example without Enums?

Comment: @NepoZnat Edited with another solution